# Add target=“_blank” to link with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Simple question:
How do you add target=“_blank” to the returned link in the following function?

```
   String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
    return this.replace(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(t) {
        var tag = t.replace("#","%23")
        return t.link("http://search.twitter.com/search?q="+tag);
    });
```

It is printed like this:

```
$("#twitterFeed span").html(data[twitterNumber].text.replace(urlRegexp, "<a target=_blank href='$1'>$1</a>").parseHashtag().parseUsername());
```

Comment: `target` is an HTML attribute. The hashtag is part of the URL. You can't add an HTML attribute into an URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to do it yourself:

```
return t.link("http://search.twitter.com/search?q="+tag)
    .replace(/^<a/, '$& target="_blank"');
```